# In Dune, how do they communicate between planets?

Tags: dune, communication

In the Dune books, I couldn't understand how interplanetary communications work. Is there a real-time way of communications, or do they depend on Guild ships to make the trip, and thats how they get messages across?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Repeated throughout the Dune novels a reader will find "communications room".

Example from *Heretics of Dune*:

> A tall Reverend Mother came from the
>   adjoining communications room. "Mother
>   Commander," she said, "the messages
>   have been sent to Guild, Ix, and
>   Tleilaxu."

And about 30 lines later a reader can find this:

> The Reverend Mother from the
>   communications room returned, glanced
>   once at Sheeana and spoke to Odrade.
>   "Chapter House acknowledges receipt of
>   your report. They approve your
>   response

Which makes me think they had those working as real time communications in place.

Maybe they were using something like [ansible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ansible) for this?

But then I was just reading Dune Encyclopedia and found this:

> The centrality crucial to Imperial
>   administration administration was 
>   impossible  to  maintain  when  there 
>   was  no quick method of  communication
>   from  one  end of the  Empire to the 
>   other — and until the discovery of
>   Holtzman Waves,  the only way to send
>   a message was to send a ship, which
>   made for impossibly  expensive
>   administrative costs,  and diffused 
>   the  power  of  the emperor 
>   irreparably.
>
> In 7562  B.G.,  I.V.  Holtzman
>   discovered  the  Holtzman  Wave;  in
>   7556  E.G.   he  passed  on 
>   information necessary  for  its  use 
>   to  six planetary systems
>
> Also in 7556, his research was
>   interrupted  and he  was  unable  to 
>   resume  it  until  his  orbit  brought
>   him back  within panel  range  of  his
>   sun.  In  his second  return  (5694 
>   E.G.), Holtzman kept  silent; 
>   however,  he  evidently  used  this 
>   period  to discover the  curious 
>   "existence"  of  the  pointsource 
>   node.  On his  third pass  (3832
>   B.G.),  Holtzman  was  able  to 
>   communicate  freely  after  some 
>   initial difficulties were overcome,
>   and on that  pass he published the
>   theory that led to the  development 
>   of  the  twodimensional  Holtzman 
>   Effect,  the famed  Defensive  Shield.
>
> Theoretically, the range of a Holtzman
>   Wave is infinite; in practice,  its 
>   effective  range  is  limited by  the
>   ability of the sender to aim the wave
>   so  that  it  will  strike a  large 
>   (planetary  or larger)  mass  at  or 
>   near  the  receiver.  This 
>   requirement  limits  the  useful range
>   of  Holtzman  Wave  communications  to
>   approximately  250 light-years without
>   re-broadcasting.
>
> (...)
>
> Improvement  came  with  the Holtzman  Wave,  nationally  a 
>   mathematical  phenomenon  causing
>   microcatastrophic  folds  in  real 
>   spacetime along  a  selectable 
>   vector, when  the  vector  impacts 
>   with  matter  denser  than 
>   interstellar  hydrogen,  it excites 
>   that  matter  to  emit long  radio 
>   waves,  which  can then be  received 
>   on normal  radio  antennae.  With 
>   interstellar  communication now
>   possible,  navigation  could be 
>   enormously improved.

This makes me believe that they were using HE with Communication Rooms 
to the extent that HE allowed and then the message would reach the target planet 
via another planet.

Comment: Good answer, but don't forget that the Dune Encyclopedia is - explicitly - *not* canon. It is written from an in-universe perspective (just post-Scattering), and subject to the knowledge, or lack of same, that writers from that era would have. That's not to say that Holtzman Waves don't exist, just that you shouldn't rely on the DE.

Answer (score 8):

In *The Dune Encyclopedia* there was a concept called "Holtzmann Waves" which were a 1 dimensional incarnation of the 2 dimensional defensive shield and the three dimensional suspensor nullification effect. This could be used for instantaneous communication across interstellar distances.

I don't believe this is considered canon though.

Comment: [Holtzman Waves](http://dune.wikia.com/wiki/Holtzman_Effect/DE) were the one-dimensional incarnations of the HE. The only known method for interstellar communications or communicating with a ship in transit

Answer (score 7):

Also, there is the Tachion net for the post-Dune novels especially, although Daniel and Marty appear in the last book of FH.

> The Net, or Tachyon Net as it came to be called, was a galaxies wide instrument of communication, particle manipulation, and entity envelopment developed by the Outside Enemy. The elderly couple Daniel and Marty tried to ensnare the no-ship manned by Duncan Idaho, with their tachyon net.

[Source](http://dune.wikia.com/wiki/Net,_the/XD)

Also Omnius communicates through *update ships* (a system that proves flawed), probably:

```
apt-get upgrade omnius
```

Answer (score 2):

Ships with Holtzmann engines. (There's nothing to indicate that no-ships used a different type of engine; they just had the no-tech cloaking.)